# Where are my "storage PD capacity" charges coming from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, persistent-storage, google-cloud-billing

I'm new to google cloud. I'm managing several users who are testing it out and I run the lab so have to figure out what it's costing us.

I'm trying to understand where the charges come from. Here's current charge estimate:
[image]

The bit that confuses me is the "Storage PD capacity" part. I get that this is 'Persistent Disk Storage' but I cannot see which VMs it is associated with. From the charge breakdown I can see that there is 481GB that we are being charged for. But here is the disk space associated with current compute engine instances:

[image]

So there is only one instance that has a disk allocated which even could contain 481 GB. But if I ssh into that and check how much disc space is used with `df -h` then it shows only 38 GB is being used:

[image]

So where is the 481 GB coming from? How do I figure this out?

Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Storage PD capacity is the cost of Persistent disk, attached or not to a VM. It's space reserved for you and thus you need to pay for it, even if you store nothing in it.

Now, why 481? Firstly, London is Europe-west2 region. If you take all the disk in this region, the total is 500 + 100 + 10 = 610Gb.

Your billing report ends on the 25, if you take 610Gb over only 25 days, you get 491Gb (610/31*25), roughly what you see (depend on exactly when the billing has been figured out)

Comment: Amazing, thanks ever so much for the clear answer, hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An explanation might be that you are using [persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs), as they

> are located independently from your virtual machine

as oposed to [Local SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#localssds), which

> are physically attached to the server that hosts your VM instance

I believe you have the Local SSD option in mind, so have a look at the configurations of your project to figure out which one it is.